# Need some type of shortcut

Tags: linux, terminal

So first thing, I am not good Linux really beyond mildly advanced commands. I need some type of short cut from one fake folder called SD-card to a real folder called system/advt so whenever something writes to SD-card it's saved to advt. This has been bugging me with symlinks and stuff.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the distinction between "fake" and "real" folders?

Answer (score 3):

Your exact use case is not clear, but you may be able to use symlinks:

```
ln -s /system/advt /sdcard
```

If this does not work, which probably means that you run applications attempting to access /sdcard in a chroot, or similar, you could try to use a bind mount (or recursive bind mount to include submounts, if necessary):

```
mount --bind  /sdcard /system/advt  # Bind mount
mount --rbind /sdcard /system/advt  # Recursive bind mount
```

You can add this to your fstab for persistence:

```
/sdcard /system/advt none bind 0 0
```

Comment: It'd be easier if I explained what I am trying to do. My android phone has a broken sd reader so I checked and sdcard is symlinked to mnt/sdcard so I need mnt/sdcard and anything that tries to write Their to goto system/advt.

Comment: @jojo In what way does using a symlink not accomplish that? You may also need to disable automount, but I have little idea how Android does this, I believe it uses `/etc/vold.fstab`, but I don't know how that works. Please be more specific in future. This is also an XY problem: you should be asking about how to achieve your goal, not how to achieve a subtask that you *percieve* to be related to your goal.

Comment: @jojo: Sure you are working on correct mount? Here `/mnt/sdcard` is the internal storage, not the extra slot for extra memory cards. That would be `/mnt/extSdCard`.